# Issue when generate random vectors with limits on matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, random

I have a problem, I want to generate a table of 4 columns and 1 line, and with integers in the range 0 to 9, without repeating and are random each time it is run.

arrives to this, but I have a problem I always generates a 0 in the first element. And i dont know how to put a limit of 0-9

anyone who can help me?

**Code of Function:**

```
function [ n ] = generar(  )

n = [-1 -1 -1 -1];

    for i = 1:4
        r=abs(i);
        dig=floor((r-floor(r))*randn);
            while find (n == dig)
                r=r+1;
                dig=dig+floor(r-randn);
            end
        n(i)=dig;
    end
end
```

**And the results:**

```
generar()

ans =

 0     3     9     6

generar()

ans =

 0     2     4     8
```

I dont know if this post is a duplicate, but i need help with my specific problem.

Comment: Did you want to do this with C++ or Matlab? Why it is tagged with both?

Comment: matlab is based on c++ or c and was a recommended tag, sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: No need to apologize at all--just trying to be sure what you really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you want matlab, because the code you supplied is matlab, you can simply do this:

```
randperm(10, 4) - 1
```

This will give you 4 unique random numbers from `0-9`.

Comment: i try that, but when running the application, it crash

Comment: That one line should replace your entire `generar()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting there is `randsample(n, k)` where `n` is an integer, then a random sample of size `k` will be drawn from the population `1:n` (as a column vector). So for your case, you would get the result by:

```
randsample(10, 4)' - 1
```

It draws 4 random numbers from the population without replacement and all with same weights. This might be slower than `randperm(10, 4) - 1` as its real strength comes with the ability to pass over population vectors for more sophisticated examples.

Alternatively one can call it with `randsample(pop, k)` where `pop` is the population-vector of which you want to draw a random sample of size `k`. So for your case, one would do:

```
randsample(0:9, 4)
```

The result will have the same singleton dimension as the population-vector, which in this case is a row vector.
Just to offer another solution and get you in touch with `randsample()`.

Comment: I'll try and tell you